# Select whole text of UITextView using Swift

Tags: swift, uitextview, uitextrange

I tried to do this the same way as I'm doing it with a `UITextField`:

```
textView.selectedTextRange = textView.textRange(from: textView.beginningOfDocument, to: textView.endOfDocument)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should make the text field **the first responder** before selecting it:

```
textView.becomeFirstResponder()
textView.selectedTextRange = textView.textRange(from: textView.beginningOfDocument, to: textView.endOfDocument)
```

...or, better yet, just call `selectAll`:

```
textView.selectAll(self)
```